# Image Upload in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, java-server

I want to add the image name to my database and the image to the folder but i dont know what am i doing wrong, Both the coding for the database uploading and the form is given below:

```
    <form method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="imgUpload.jsp">
        <input type="file" name="image">
        <input type="submit" >
    </form>
```

and for the jsp coding:

```
try{
    String ImageFile="";
    String itemName = "";
    boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
    if (!isMultipart){
    }
    else{
        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        List items = null;
        try{
            items = upload.parseRequest(request);
        }
        catch (FileUploadException e){
            e.getMessage();
        }

    Iterator itr = items.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()){
        FileItem item = (FileItem) itr.next();
        if (item.isFormField()){
            String name = item.getFieldName();
            String value = item.getString();
            if(name.equals("image")){
                ImageFile=value;
            }
        }
        else{
            try{
                itemName = item.getName();
                File savedFile = new   File(config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"\\img\\gamePoster\\"+itemName);
                item.write(savedFile);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                out.println("Error"+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    try{
        String str="insert into test (img_name) values ('"+itemName+"')";
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        int rs=stmt.executeUpdate(str);
    }
    catch(Exception el){
        out.println("Inserting error"+el.getMessage());
    }   
   }
  }
catch (Exception e){
out.println(e.getMessage());
 }
```

Comment: Basically, if you want to store an image in the Database, you need to use the datatype blob and store the image byte by byte which I think is lacking in your code!! Google it out!!! SO also has some answers for you

Comment: Where is the problem? What's the actual question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            factory.setSizeThreshold(MEMORY_THRESHOLD);
            factory.setRepository(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));

            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            upload.setFileSizeMax(MAX_FILE_SIZE);
            upload.setSizeMax(MAX_REQUEST_SIZE); // sets maximum size of request (include file + form data)
            String uploadPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("") + File.separator + UPLOAD_DIRECTORY;

            File uploadDir = new File(uploadPath);
            if (!uploadDir.exists()) {
                uploadDir.mkdir();
            }

            List<FileItem> formItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

            if (formItems != null && formItems.size() > 0) {
                for (FileItem item : formItems) {
                    if (!item.isFormField()) {
                        String fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                        System.out.println("item.getFieldName() => "+item.getFieldName());
                        String fileAttr[] = fileName.split("\\.");
                        String newFileName = fileAttr[0];
                        int i = 1;
                        while (true) {
                            File f = new File(uploadPath + "\\" + newFileName + "." + fileAttr[1]);
                            if (f.exists()) {
                                newFileName = fileAttr[0] + i;
                                i++;
                            } else {
                                fileName = newFileName + "." + fileAttr[1];
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        String filePath = uploadPath + File.separator + fileName;
                        File storeFile = new File(filePath);
                        item.write(storeFile);
                        request.setAttribute("message","Upload has been done successfully!");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("1 item.getFieldName() => "+item.getFieldName());
                        if("description1".equalsIgnoreCase(item.getFieldName())){
                            //this part is for other field except file field
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

you have to add commons-fileupload-1.3.jar

Answer (score -2):

Try this code in your form tag

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="imgins.jsp?id=<%=id%>" method="post">
    <b><font color="white">Choose the file To Upload: </font> </b>
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

then you can insert image to database using the below code

```
<%
    String saveFile = "";
    String contentType = request.getContentType();

    if ((contentType != null) && (contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)) {
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
        int formDataLength = request.getContentLength();
        byte dataBytes[] = new byte[formDataLength];
        int byteRead = 0;
        int totalBytesRead = 0;

        while (totalBytesRead < formDataLength) {
            byteRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead, formDataLength);
            totalBytesRead += byteRead;
        }

        String file = new String(dataBytes);
        saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10);
        saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
        saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, saveFile.indexOf("\""));
        int lastIndex = contentType.lastIndexOf("=");
        String boundary = contentType.substring(lastIndex + 1, contentType.length());

        int pos;
        pos = file.indexOf("filename=\"");
        pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
        pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
        pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;

        int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4;
        int startPos = ((file.substring(0, pos)).getBytes()).length;
        int endPos = ((file.substring(0, boundaryLocation)).getBytes()).length;

        File ff = new File(saveFile);
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(ff);
        fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));
        fileOut.flush();
        fileOut.close();

        Connection connection = null;
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/movie";
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement psmnt = null;
        FileInputStream fis;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "root");

            File f = new File(saveFile);
            int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id").toString());
            psmnt = connection.prepareStatement("update movie set image=? where movie_id=?");
            fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            psmnt.setBinaryStream(1, (InputStream) fis, (int) (f.length()));

            psmnt.setInt(2, id);
            out.println("hi");
            int s = psmnt.executeUpdate();

            if (s > 0) {
                System.out.println("Uploaded successfully !");
                response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
%>
```

Comment: Never ever ever put parameters in the `action` attribute of a form...ever. They'll just get stripped off.

Comment: I have used parameters in lots of pages in jsp in the action attribute only it works fine.

Comment: With GET, it might. With POST it most certainly will not. And its bad practice either way. Just make an `input` and put the value in it.

Comment: nops, i dont want to store them, i only want to store the name of the image to the DB. and the image to the folder.